# how to design blog commenting system with django orm?

Tags: python, django, post, comments, blogs

I am new to Django and I am wondering how can I design a nested commenting system for my blog project?

```
class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   paragraph = models.TextField()
   sources = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return f'||{self.title}|| from -> {self.author}'


class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    mail = models.EmailField()
    content = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    reply = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} said --> {self.content}'
```

I tried this for models and, it doesn't seem to work for nested comments.
And also this is my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post, Comment
from django import forms

class PostsView(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

class PostsDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'

class NewPost(generic.CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'test_form.html'
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'paragraph', 'sources']
    success_url = "/posts"

def commenter(request, post_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = Post.objects.get(id= post_id)
        comment = request.POST.get('comment')
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        new_comment = Comment(name=name, mail=email, comment=comment, post=post)
        new_comment.save()
        return HttpResponse('okay')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('failed')
```

Is there any ways to create a commenting system like mongodb nested documents in django models ?

Comment: I don't think you need nested comment. The reply attribute of comment should be a CharField like this:  `reply = models.CharField(max_length=500)`. Also update your question with your view where you use it.

Comment: You could just try putting a `ForeignKey` Field to `Comment` in your Comment model, and not to "self". Something similar to recursion